# Angular 5 + Django - How to handle user permissions

Tags: django, angular, permissions

I have an Angular v5 application backed by Django REST Framework.

Previously the application was totally relying on Django templates.
Now, I'm using Angular and it is not clear to me how permissions are should be managed.

The application has different sections. Regarding the product section, the permissions can be summed up as follow:

**Course grain permissions**

1. Can the user see a product?
2. Can the user change a product?
3. Can the user delete a product?
4. Can the user create a product?

**Fine grain permissions**

1. Can the user see product SKU?
2. Can the user see product pricing?
3. ...

Fine-grained permissions are very important because there're users that can see the product list where on Angular has been implemented as a table, but few users cannot see certain columns.

My question is how I can handle permissions on Django and Angular?

**Permissions on Django**

How to design fine-grained permissions on Django and change the serializers accordingly?

**Permissions on Angular**

My idea was, when the user logs in, Angular got from backend all user permissions and then Angular will change the view accordingly.
Anyway, I don't think this is a safe solution since permissions can easily manipulated by the user from JS console.

What's usually the best practice for this?

Comment: This seems far too vague. But surely your backend should only send the data that the user is allowed to see.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman. Yes, it's really a generic question, but I don't know where to start. I would need a reference to follow.

Comment: You should define permissions classes in Django, http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: Thanks @JerinPeterGeorge for your reply. I know how to define DRF permissions, but I'm not able to change serializers based on user permissions. What I mean is, if the user cannot see product price how I can hide product price in the serializer?

Comment: @Fabio i am also stuck at this point, but i am using class base views instead of DRF, and using Angular 4. and i have custom user model and custom user authentication not using groups of django either, django version 1.10, i don't understand either where to start my work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @jahmed31 I'm still working on the project. However the user permissions should be checked both on backend and frontend. Basically backend/Django should deny access to views where the user doesn't have right permissions and frontend/Angular should change the templates according to user permissions. With Django, if you're using regular views and not DRF, you can use the `permission_required` decorator to allow access to only users that have a specific permission.

Comment: For Angular, the approach that I'm using is: when the user authenticate, he receives the auth token (I'm using JWT) and I'm including the full list of all user permissions. However @jahmed31, my project is still in progress, but I would really appreciate other users' approaches and/or feedbacks.

Comment: @Fabio okay how we implemented in our project with different approach. We added all permissions in json file, like permission name, permission and the roles for that permissions. So on front end, list of menu and roles been checked. In database we have added roles for each permission. When ever user got logged in we sent his complete permissions and on front end implement all those permissions at once.